# if rows equal true update if not insert php

Tags: php, sql-server

EDIT: Hello!

Environment: Wamp with PHP 7.1.15 and DB SQL server.

I would like to update if a field exists otherwise insert a new line.

I use "sql_has_rows" to check if a line already exists or not.
When the query is executed, the browser does not display an error but no modification of the table is made

EDIT:2

```
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable where Client = '$Client' and Contact = '$Contact' and Jira = '$Jira'";
$params1 = array($Client, $Jira, $Contact, $lvlsatisfaction, $Commentaire);                       
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $stmt, $params1);

if ($result) {
   $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows( $result ); 
   if ($rows === false){
    "INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (Client, Jira, Contact, lvlsatisfaction, Commentaire, DateEnregistrement, HeureEnregistrement)
    values (?,?,?,?,?, convert (date, getdate()), convert (time, getdate()))";
   }else{
    "UPDATE dbo.MyTable set lvlsatisfaction = (?), Commentaire = (?), DateEnregistrement = (convert (date, getdate())), HeureEnregistrement = (convert (time, getdate()))
    where Client = '$Client' and Contact = '$Contact' and Jira = '$Jira'" ;
}
```

}

Comment: So you select rows from dbo.MyTable, but you insert or update rows in dbo.Formulaire. So which table are you checking when you claim "no modification of **the** table is made"?

Comment: Indeed, I put "MyTable" so that it is more understandable, I corrected the post. I tried to put just two parameters in $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $stmt) but I still encounter the same problem